# IllegalStateExcepton when working with SQLite Database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

When I run this following code, I get this exception displayed in a Toast message: `Java.lang.IllegalStateExcepton: Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 1`.

```
SQLiteDatabase sb;
    String g="o";
    try {
        sb=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("data/data/com.example.datatestx/ma", null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

        sb.execSQL("create table if not exists blac  (" + " phone text  , " + " ftime  text, " + " ttime text );  "    );

        sb.execSQL( "insert into blac(phone, ftime,ttime) values ('01711233434', '333333','33333' );"  );
        sb.execSQL( "insert into blac(phone, ftime,ttime) values ('01761233433', '777' ,'77777');"  );
        sb.execSQL( "insert into blac(phone, ftime,ttime) values ('01712333323', '999','33433' );"  );
        Cursor c1 = sb.rawQuery( "select count(*) as Total from blac", null);
    if(c1.getCount()>0){

    c1.moveToFirst();
    do {
        g=g+c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("phone"));

    }while(c1.moveToNext());
    }  c1.close();
        sb.close();

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!"+g, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
    }
```

I don't know why this is not working. Can anybody help?

Comment: Please post the whole logcat output of crash

Answer (score 0):

In your `SELECT` query you ask for `COUNT(*) as Total`, which means your result set will have one single field named 'Total' which contains the total number of rows.

So it doesn't make sense to read the `phone` field from this result set...

Try to replace

```
Cursor c1 = sb.rawQuery( "select count(*) as Total from blac", null);
```

by

```
Cursor c1 = sb.rawQuery( "select * from blac", null);
```

Comment: fiddler ,now in logcat the exception like as "sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "as": syntax error".

Comment: I edited the query a while ago, it must be `"select * from blac"` (not `"select * as Total from blac"`)